How to use Blazored.Modal to render different child components?
Good day everyone. As the title says, is it possible to show different components without closing and reopening the modal?
I would like to know a seamless way to update the body of the modal (currently I have to close the modal and open a new one which produces a flickering effect when the modal closes for a few milliseconds and opens a new one) I only want to update the body of the modal. The documentation https://blazored.github.io/Modal/ doesn't give a sample scenario. Will appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction. Thanks
I am using .NET8 Web App. I have a LoginFormComponent that has a Register Now button, and a RegisterFormComponent that has a Login Now button. I created a custom modal component called DynamicModal very much like Blazored's CustomBootstrapModal. I have a Login Button in my Home screen, this is the code:
void LoginClick()
{
    var content = new RenderFragment(builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<LoginFormComponent>(0);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    });
    var modalParams = new ModalParameters();
    modalParams.Add(nameof(DynamicModal.ChildContent), content);
    Modal.Show<DynamicModal>(modalParams);
}

The 'Register Now' button in the LoginFormComponent has the same code above (just swapped LoginFormComponent with RegisterFormComponent). The effect is one modal is stacked on top of the other, which when I click close shows the modal underneath the closed modal.
Another method that I tried was await BlazoredModal.CloseAsync() followed by Modal.Show<Component> but it doesn't look seamless because the modal closes for a few milliseconds before displaying the next form.

Hi @harrystyles18, have you tried to modify the modal content using a RenderFragment  bound to the modal's body.
